# How to convert JWK to PEM in NodeJS/Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptography, pem, jwk

I'd like to download public key from `jwk` endpoint and convert it into `pem` format that is required in `sing` function for `jwt`.

```js
export type Secret =
    | string
    | Buffer
    | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string };
```

The `jwk` format can be imported with `subtle` from `crypto` as the `webKey` of `JsonWebKey` type and returned as `CryptoKey`

```js
const pubKey = await subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    webKey,
    { hash: 'SHA-256', name: 'RSA-OAEP' },
    true,
    []
  );
```

The `CryptoKey` can be exported with `subtle.exportKey` but the result is in `ByteArray` and converting it to `pem` with 1. converting bytes to chars then 2. to base64 and adding it to `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` with envelope with adding new line every 64 characters produces an **invalid key**.

```js
/**
 * Exports the given key into the specified format, if supported.
 *
 * If the `<CryptoKey>` is not extractable, the returned promise will reject.
 *
 * When `format` is either `'pkcs8'` or `'spki'` and the export is successful,
 * the returned promise will be resolved with an `<ArrayBuffer>` containing the exported key data.
 *
 * When `format` is `'jwk'` and the export is successful, the returned promise will be resolved with a
 * JavaScript object conforming to the {@link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517 JSON Web Key} specification.
 * @param format Must be one of `'raw'`, `'pkcs8'`, `'spki'`, or `'jwk'`.
 * @returns `<Promise>` containing `<ArrayBuffer>`.
 * @since v15.0.0
 */
exportKey(format: 'jwk', key: CryptoKey): Promise<JsonWebKey>;
exportKey(format: Exclude<KeyFormat, 'jwk'>, key: CryptoKey): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
```

Also, the pub key can be exported only to `spki` and `jwk` the `raw` is not supported.

The question in how to convert `jwk` to `pem` as simply as possible?!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is converting `CryptoKey` to `KeyObject` with `static from(key: webcrypto.CryptoKey): KeyObject;` and then use `export(options: KeyExportOptions<'pem'>): string | Buffer;` that is member of `KeyObject`.

The function would be

```js
export async function jwkToPem(webKey: JsonWebKey): Promise<string> {
  const cryptoKey = await subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    webKey,
    { hash: 'SHA-256', name: 'RSA-OAEP' },
    true,
    []
  );

  return KeyObject.from(cryptoKey).export({ format: "pem", type: "pkcs1"}).toString();
}
```

### Topaco's suggestion

It could be even easier using `createPublicKey` that accepts `JsonWebKeyInput` and produces `KeyObject` that could be easily exported.

```js
    /**
     * Creates and returns a new key object containing a public key. If `key` is a
     * string or `Buffer`, `format` is assumed to be `'pem'`; if `key` is a `KeyObject`with type `'private'`, the public key is derived from the given private key;
     * otherwise, `key` must be an object with the properties described above.
     *
     * If the format is `'pem'`, the `'key'` may also be an X.509 certificate.
     *
     * Because public keys can be derived from private keys, a private key may be
     * passed instead of a public key. In that case, this function behaves as if {@link createPrivateKey} had been called, except that the type of the
     * returned `KeyObject` will be `'public'` and that the private key cannot be
     * extracted from the returned `KeyObject`. Similarly, if a `KeyObject` with type`'private'` is given, a new `KeyObject` with type `'public'` will be returned
     * and it will be impossible to extract the private key from the returned object.
     * @since v11.6.0
     */
    function createPublicKey(key: PublicKeyInput | string | Buffer | KeyObject | JsonWebKeyInput): KeyObject;
```

then

```js
export async function jwkToPem(webKey: JsonWebKey): Promise<string> {
  const pubKey: KeyObject = createPublicKey({
    key: webKey,
    format: 'jwk'
  });

  return pubKey.export({ format: "pem", type: "pkcs1"}).toString();
}
```

Comment: Import is much easier with `createPrivateKey()` (or `createPublicKey()`). JWKs are supported from v15.12.0.